# How full is my iPhone voicemail box?

Tags: visual-voicemail

I want to be able to know how full my voicemail box is *before* it starts rejecting caller's messages. Is there a command that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what carrier you have you can try the following:

- If you have visual voice mail you should be warned when you are at or near the limit in Phone > Voicemail
- Try calling your own number. Most carriers use that to access your voicemail. If it asks for a password, it will most likely default to the last 4 digits of your phone number. Once connected it will most likely tell you if your voice mail is full. You can also delete messages from there.
- If the above option does not work, call your carrier and ask how to access your voicemail.
- If all else fails you call from a different phone (house phone or friend) and test it out. You could also use a spoofing service and call your own number.